# Split a column using delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with values like `AAA-BBB-CCC` or `AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD`.

I am only interested in splitting and retrieving `AAA BBB CCC`.

I've tried using `PARSENAME`, however that messes up.

Comment: Which database you're working on? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Will the input values always have 3 and 4 groups (2 and 3 dashes), or are there other values passed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7554ea/5)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([value] varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([value])
VALUES
    ('AAA-BBB-CCC'),
    ('AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD'),
    ('AAAAA-BBBB-CCCC'),
    ('AAAAA-BBBB-CCCCCC-DDD'),
    ('AAAAAA-BBB-CCC'),
    ('AAAAAAAA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDD-EEEE')

;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT replace(
          substring(value,1,(
               case when charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1) = 0 
                    then len(value)
                    else charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1)-1 end
          )),'-',' ')
FROM Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7554ea/5/0)**:

```
|               COLUMN_0 |
|------------------------|
|            AAA BBB CCC |
|            AAA BBB CCC |
|        AAAAA BBBB CCCC |
|      AAAAA BBBB CCCCCC |
|         AAAAAA BBB CCC |
| AAAAAAAA BBBBBB CCCCCC |
```

OR

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7554ea/5)

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT value,
       PARSENAME(replace(
          substring(value,1,(
               case when charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1) = 0 
                    then len(value)
                    else charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1)-1 end
          )),'-','.'),3) as '1st',
       PARSENAME(replace(
          substring(value,1,(
               case when charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1) = 0 
                    then len(value)
                    else charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1)-1 end
          )),'-','.'),2) as '2nd',
       PARSENAME(replace(
          substring(value,1,(
               case when charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1) = 0 
                    then len(value)
                    else charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value,charindex('-',value)+1)+1)-1 end
          )),'-','.'),1) as '3rd'
FROM Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7554ea/5/0)**:

```
|                           VALUE |      1ST |    2ND |    3RD |
|---------------------------------|----------|--------|--------|
|                     AAA-BBB-CCC |      AAA |    BBB |    CCC |
|                 AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD |      AAA |    BBB |    CCC |
|                 AAAAA-BBBB-CCCC |    AAAAA |   BBBB |   CCCC |
|           AAAAA-BBBB-CCCCCC-DDD |    AAAAA |   BBBB | CCCCCC |
|                  AAAAAA-BBB-CCC |   AAAAAA |    BBB |    CCC |
| AAAAAAAA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDD-EEEE | AAAAAAAA | BBBBBB | CCCCCC |
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be using replace function like so:

```
select replace(columnName, '-', ' ') as SplittedVal
```

If only AAA BBB CCC is needed and the values are formated like 3 characters space 3 characters  space 3 characters (so 11 characters in total) then use:

```
select left(replace(columnName, '-', ' '), 11)
```

Comment: @user406151, is the pattern in the updated answer correct? so 3 chars space 3 chars space 3 chars (total 11 chars) ? If so then that should be the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, your only intention is to replace `-` with a whitespace. IF that is so, just use `REPLACE` function.

```
SELECT REPLACE('abcdefghicde','cde','xxx');
do
```

SO, your code will be

```
SELECT REPLACE('AAA-BBB-CCC','-',' ');
do
```

Comment: This will return DDD only when you pass the second string in your question. Does this mean, you only want first three character sets which are separated by hyphen (without hyphen) in your result?

Comment: First three character sets.